# opentbs - How can I set document title programmatically?

Tags: php, opentbs

I use OpenTBS 1.9.6 for generation of OpenOffice odt documents. I need to set title in document properties programmatically.

I have set placeholder in document properties title. But it doesn't work.

the variable is set global with $TBS->VarRef

Is there any way? Thanks

[image: placeholder in document properties]

I use OpenTBS 1.9.6 and TinyButStrong 3.10.1. I work with odt file created by OpenOffice 4.1.5.

```
`        include_once($this->context->parameters['appDir'] . '/openTBS/tbs_class.php'); // Load the TinyButStrong template engine
        include_once($this->context->parameters['appDir'] . '/openTBS/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php'); // Load the OpenTBS plugin
```

`$TBS = new \App\openTBS\clsTinyButStrong;
    $TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
    $TBS->LoadTemplate($this->context->parameters['documents_path'] .'templates/'. $templateName, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);

    $res = $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, 'meta.xml');
    Debugger::log('OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE: '.$res); 
// function returned false

    $res = $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY, 'meta.xml', 'office:document-meta/office:meta/dc:title', false, "My title", true);
    Debugger::log('OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY: '.$res);
// function returned false`

`

odt file structure looks this way:

[image]

meta.xml looks this way:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-meta xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:textooo="http://openoffice.org/2013/office" office:version="1.2"><office:meta><meta:initial-creator>Lubor Voleský</meta:initial-creator><meta:creation-date>2019-01-09T22:04:27.08</meta:creation-date><dc:date>2020-04-07T18:30:26</dc:date><meta:editing-duration>PT20H5M8S</meta:editing-duration><meta:editing-cycles>26</meta:editing-cycles><meta:generator>OpenOffice/4.1.5$Unix OpenOffice.org_project/415m1$Build-9789</meta:generator><dc:description>comment</dc:description><meta:keyword>keywords</meta:keyword><dc:subject>Subject</dc:subject><dc:title>Title</dc:title><meta:document-statistic meta:table-count="1" meta:image-count="1" meta:object-count="0" meta:page-count="1" meta:paragraph-count="19" meta:word-count="39" meta:character-count="256"/><meta:user-defined meta:name="Producer">OpenTBS 1.9.6</meta:user-defined></office:meta></office:document-meta>

Answer (score 0):

Those properties are in the `meta.xml` sub-file. So you simply have to open it and then automatic fields (onload, onshow) will be processed:

```
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, 'meta.xml');
```

You can also use special commands (slower):

```
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY, 'meta.xml', 'office:document-meta/office:meta/dc:subject',     false, "My subject", true);
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY, 'meta.xml', 'office:document-meta/office:meta/dc:title',       false, "My title", true);
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY, 'meta.xml', 'office:document-meta/office:meta/dc:description', false, "My description", true);
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY, 'meta.xml', 'office:document-meta/office:meta/meta:keyword',   false, "My keywords", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I don't know what I do wrong. 
Both $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, 'meta.xml') and  $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, 'meta.xml') return false.
I use OpenTBS 1.9.6 and TinyButStrong 3.10.1. I work with odt file created by OpenOffice 4.1.5.
I added code excerpt in my question up. Thanks

Comment: It is not easy to install LibreOffice 4 when version 6 is already installed. Can you make some tests to see in which sub-file your information are stored ?

Comment: I added odt structure and meta.xml into the question up. Your code looks to be correct. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Neither do I. I’ve tested the two solution and both are working for me. We can see at your `meta.xml` contents that OpenTBS had success to insert the credit « OpenTBS 1.9.6 ». So it can reach and edit this file. It could be good if you can send to me a snippet to reproduce your bug.

Comment: Functions returned false. Code snippet is in descriptio up.